# How to display empty stars on products with woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, e-commerce, rating

How do I display a rating at all times, even if it is empty? This is for woocommerce, meant for product boxes like popular products and new products, doesn't have to show up on single product pages.

Comment: @TemaniAfif That's the opposite of what he's asking.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to your functions.php

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','change_loop_ratings_location', 2 );
function change_loop_ratings_location(){
remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 5 );
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 15 );
}
```

And then after add the following lines also to get the rating count

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_rating_html', 'loop_product_get_rating_html', 20, 3 );
function loop_product_get_rating_html( $html, $rating, $count ){
    if ( 0 < $rating && ! is_product() ) {
        global $product;
        $rating_cnt = array_sum($product->get_rating_counts());
        $count_html = ' <div class="count-rating">' . $rating_cnt .'</div>';

        $html       = '<div class="container-rating"><div class="star-rating">';
        $html      .= wc_get_star_rating_html( $rating, $count );
        $html      .= '</div>' . $count_html . '</div>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your functions.php:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_rating_html',function ( $html, $rating, $count){
    $label = sprintf( __( 'Rated %s out of 5', 'woocommerce' ), $rating );
    $html  ='<div class="star-rating" role="img" aria-label="' . esc_attr( $label ) . '">' . wc_get_star_rating_html( $rating, $count ) . '</div>';
    return $html;
},9999,3);
```